# Automatically Populating Account on Contracts Created from Opportunity

Tags: custom-field, field-update, standard-objects, automation

My company has just started using Contracts. We would like our sales reps and managers to create the Contract from Opportunities. I added a custom field called Opportunity__c which is a lookup to the Opportunity.

The issue I am facing is that when a Contract is created from the Opportunity under the Related Lists section, the Account Name lookup field is not being populated with the opportunity account. This causes the sales rep or manager to have to search for it and enter it manually. It would be nice if they didn't have to do that.

I thought I could build a Process or Workflow Rule that would populate that when a record is created. However, the Account Name field defaults to NULL and is required upon creation.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I could get the standard Account Name field on the Contract to auto populate when a Contract is created from the Opportunity?

Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a "quick action".
Go to Setup => Object Manager => Buttons, Links, and Actions and press "New Action"

Choose Create a Record as Action type, Target Object should be Contract and Label could be something like "New Contract".
Choose the fields required to create the Contract (to add to the layout).

Than comes the "magic".

After you save the new quick action you are presented with your new action and you can add "Predefined Field Values".

There you can add the Opportunity, the Account etc. to be populated from information already known on the opportunity.
The result should leave you with something like the following image:
[image: New Contract Result]

Add this button to your page layout and you're done.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I really appreciate it. Have a great Christmas and a very happy New Year.